# Kendo UI grid does not show edited value, when using angular-kendo.js and the field is defined in the schema / model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

In the following example the edited FirstName, will not be shown after it's updated.
But when I remove the FirstName field from the dataSource.schema.model the changes are shown.

**Before edit**
[image]

**Edit**

[image]

**After edit**

[image]

In the Google Chrome Developer extension for Kendo UI, I can see the firstName is removed from the model and a property "model" is added to the record instead of the firstName property:

```
data: Array[7]
    0: Object{3}
        Id: 1
        LastName: "ln_1"
        models: Array[1]
            0: Object{3}
                Id: 1
                FirstName: "fn_1_changed_to_something_else"
                LastName: "ln_1"
    1: Object{3}
        Id: 2
        FirstName: "fn_2"
        LastName: "ln_2"
        ....
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

*Example html page*

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kendo UI directives for AngularJS</title>
    <link href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-kendo.js"></script>
    <script>
        var demoApp = angular.module("demoApp", ["kendo.directives"]);
        demoApp.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.employees = [
                { Id: 1, FirstName: "fn_1", LastName: "ln_1" },
                { Id: 2, FirstName: "fn_2", LastName: "ln_2" },
                { Id: 3, FirstName: "fn_3", LastName: "ln_3" },
                { Id: 4, FirstName: "fn_4", LastName: "ln_4" },
                { Id: 5, FirstName: "fn_5", LastName: "ln_5" },
                { Id: 6, FirstName: "fn_6", LastName: "ln_6" },
                { Id: 7, FirstName: "fn_7", LastName: "ln_7" }
            ];

            $scope.mainGridOptions = {
                dataSource: {
                    data: $scope.employees,
                    batch: true,
                    pageSize: 5,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "Id",
                            fields: {
                                FirstName: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } }
                                //LastName: { editable: true }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                editable: "popup",
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                columns: [{
                    field: "FirstName",
                    title: "First Name",
                    width: "120px"
                }, {
                    field: "LastName",
                    title: "Last Name",
                    width: "120px"
                },
                {
                    command: [{
                        name: "edit",
                        text: { edit: "Custom edit", cancel: "Custom cancel", update: "Custom update" }
                    }
                    , { name: "destroy", text: "Remove" }
                    ]
                }]
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    <div>
        <div kendo-grid k-options="mainGridOptions"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: 
You should not use the datasource **batch** option, when working with local data.

As confirmed by Mihai Bazon.

After changing the batch option to false everything worked well again.

Comment: lol.............How you are determining what type of events it  is ?   like update , delete ..?